# WebGL: INVALID_OPERATION: uniformMatrix4fv: location is not from current program

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

I am trying to pass data from the server to the client to move a 3D cube in a UP and Down motion simulating `accelerometer` data. But I am receiving this error on the browser.

```
WebGL: INVALID_OPERATION: uniformMatrix4fv: location is not from current program
```

[image]

Basically, no matter what I do the browser keeps complaining about `uniformMatrix4fv`.

I tried to use firefox, edge, chrome, I also tried to use different versions of three.js and three.min.js but the error persisted. What does this error mean? and how to fix it?

This is my code (.js)

```
if (!!window.EventSource) {
  var source = new EventSource('/sse')
  source.addEventListener('message', function (e) {        
    function main() {

      const canvas = document.querySelector('#canvas');
      const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ canvas });
      var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

      const fov = 60;
      const aspect = 2;
      const near = 0.1;
      const far = 2000;
      const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(fov, aspect, near, far);

      camera.position.x = 0;
      camera.position.y = 40;
      camera.position.z = 0;
      camera.lookAt (new THREE.Vector3(0,0,1));

      const scene = new THREE.Scene();
      {

        planeSize
        const color = 0xFFFFFF;
        const intensity = 1;
        const size = 10;
        const divisions = 10;
        var planeSize = 200000;
        const light = new THREE.PointLight(color, intensity);
        const gridHelper = new THREE.GridHelper( planeSize, 10000 );

        gridHelper.geometry.rotateY( Math.PI / 2 );
        scene.add(gridHelper);
        
        scene.add(light);
      }
      const objects = [];
      const radius = 3;
      const widthSegments = 3;
      const heightSegments = 3;
      const sphereGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(radius, widthSegments, heightSegments);
      const sunMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: "green", wireframe: false });
      const sunMesh = new THREE.Mesh(sphereGeometry, sunMaterial);

      var cubeAxis = new THREE.AxesHelper(10);
      sunMesh.add(cubeAxis);

      sunMesh.scale.set(2, 2, 2);
      scene.add(sunMesh);
      objects.push(sunMesh);

      function resizeRendererToDisplaySize(renderer) {
        const canvas = renderer.domElement;
        const width = canvas.clientWidth;
        const height = canvas.clientHeight;
        const needResize = canvas.width !== width || canvas.height !== height;
        if (needResize) {
          renderer.setSize(width, height, false);
        }
        return needResize;
      }
      function animation() {
        
        if (resizeRendererToDisplaySize(renderer)) {
          const canvas = renderer.domElement;
          camera.aspect = canvas.clientWidth / canvas.clientHeight;
          camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
        }
        var json = JSON.parse(JSON.parse(e.data))

        if (json !== null) {

          accZ = json['value'];
          console.log(accZ);
          
          objects.forEach((obj) => {
            obj.position.z = accZ;
            var relativeCameraOffset = new THREE.Vector3 (0,20,0); // change camera offset
            var cameraOffset = relativeCameraOffset.applyMatrix4( obj.matrixWorld );
            camera.position.x = cameraOffset.x;
            camera.position.z = cameraOffset.z;
            camera.lookAt( obj.position );
          });
        } 
        renderer.render(scene, camera);
        requestAnimationFrame(animation);
      }
      requestAnimationFrame(animation);
    }
    
    main();
  }, false)

  source.addEventListener('open', function (e) {
    // document.getElementById('state').innerHTML = "Connected"
  }, false)

  source.addEventListener('error', function (e) {
    const id_state = document.getElementById('state')
    if (e.eventPhase == EventSource.CLOSED)
      source.close()
    if (e.target.readyState == EventSource.CLOSED) {
      id_state.innerHTML = "Disconnected"
    }
    else if (e.target.readyState == EventSource.CONNECTING) {
      id_state.innerHTML = "Connecting..."
    }
  }, false)
} else {
  console.log("Your browser doesn't support SSE")
}
```

Comment: no, unfortunately, I don't think it is relevant to my problem, I couldn't solve mine by looking at this thread

Comment: Please try to reproduce the issue with a [live example](https://jsfiddle.net/npza1q38/) or by sharing a GitHub repo.

Comment: The problem is now solved, since my question is clashing with another similar question, I cannot answer it in a new thread, so I will add a very short answer here: Basically, the solution is to remove function main() out of source.addEventListener('message', function (e) and place it separately and the access the event.data value from 'message' function back to function main(), that way no WebGL or context loss errors

Comment: Answer is here too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66631085/js-sse-cannot-access-event-data-outside-of-onmsg-callback-function/66632180?noredirect=1#comment117795859_66632180