# JS SSE: Cannot access event.data outside of onMsg callback function?

Tags: javascript, html, server, three.js, server-sent-events

I am using three.js to visualize accelerometer data in real-time and in 3D on the browser. I am using server-sent-event to transfer data from the remote server to the client side.

I've got three.js code up and running on simulated data and without rendering issues. Now when I try to use SSE on the remote server, I found that I can only read data from onMsg, onOpen, onError callback functions

For this reason, I placed three.js implementation inside onMsg callback, but in this case the browser was running forever and it doesn't show the render basically, it goes in an infinite loop, so I figured that I should not include any other function in Onmsg, therefore, I separated three.js code from SSE, but now I am not able to access the event.data from the Onmsg and send them back to the function main() which responsible of rendering the 3D model.

Below is my code:

It only renders the 3D model (it's static) and I can see the data in JSON format on the developer tool window, but the data are not passed to the 3D model.

```
function main() {

    const canvas = document.querySelector('#canvas');
    const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ canvas });
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

    const fov = 70;
    const aspect = 2;
    const near = 20;
    const far = 500;
    const color = 0xFFFFFF;
    const intensity = 1;
    const size = 10;
    const divisions = 10;
    const objects = [];
    const radius = 3;
    const widthSegments = 3;
    const heightSegments = 3;
    const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(fov, aspect, near, far);
    const sphereGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(radius, widthSegments, heightSegments);
    const sunMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: "green", wireframe: false });
    const sunMesh = new THREE.Mesh(sphereGeometry, sunMaterial)
    const light = new THREE.PointLight(color, intensity);
    // const gridHelper = new THREE.GridHelper(200000, 10000);

    camera.position.z = 0;
    camera.position.x = 100;
    camera.up.set(0, 0, 1);
    camera.lookAt(0, 0, 0);   

    const scene = new THREE.Scene();
    {
      const color = 0x00afaf;
      const intensity = 10;
      const light = new THREE.PointLight(color, intensity);
      scene.add(light);
      // gridHelper.geometry.rotateY(Math.PI / 2);
      // scene.add(gridHelper);
      // scene.add(light);
    }
    function resizeRendererToDisplaySize() {
    const canvas = renderer.domElement;
    const width = canvas.clientWidth;
    const height = canvas.clientHeight;
    const needResize = canvas.width !== width || canvas.height !== height;
    if (needResize) {
      renderer.setSize(width, height, false);
    }
    return needResize;
  }

  function resizeToClient() {
    const needResize = resizeRendererToDisplaySize()
    if (needResize) {
      const canvas = renderer.domElement;
      camera.aspect = canvas.clientWidth / canvas.clientHeight;
      camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    }
  }

    var cubeAxis = new THREE.AxesHelper(10);
    sunMesh.add(cubeAxis);

    sunMesh.scale.set(5, 5, 5)
    scene.add(sunMesh);
    scene.background = new THREE.Color(0.22, 0.23, 0.22);

    function render() {

      sunMesh.position.x = 100;
      // sunMesh.rotation.y = -70.68;
    }
    resizeToClient();
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
  }


  function onMsg(event) {
    // console.log(`[message] Data received from server: ${event.data}`);
    // console.log("event.data = " + JSON.parse(event.data));

    var received_msg = event.data;

    var obj = JSON.parse(JSON.parse(received_msg));
    if (obj !== null) {
      if (
        obj.hasOwnProperty("DataMapChangedObjectsAddressValue") &&
        obj["DataMapChangedObjectsAddressValue"][0]["DataMapAddress"] !==
        undefined
      ) {
        let sensorAddr =
          obj["DataMapChangedObjectsAddressValue"][0]["DataMapAddress"];
        let sensorValue =
          obj["DataMapChangedObjectsAddressValue"][0]["Value"];

        //Accelerometer X Axis
        //if(sensorAddr === this.despToAddrMap.get("Accelerometer X Axis Data")){
        if (sensorAddr === 3) {
          console.log((sensorValue / 16384) * 500);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  function onOpen(e) {
    console.log("SSE connected");
  }

  function onError(e) {
    // console.log(`[error] ${error.message}`);
    if (e.eventPhase == EventSource.CLOSED) this.source.close();
    if (e.target.readyState == EventSource.CLOSED) {
      console.log("SSE Disconnected");
    } else if (e.target.readyState == EventSource.CONNECTING) {
      console.log("SSE Connecting ...");
    }
  }

  function StartRetrieveLiveData() {
    if (!!window.EventSource) {
      this.source = new EventSource("/sse");
    } else {
      console.log("Your browser doesn't support SSE");
    }

    this.source.addEventListener("message", e => this.onMsg(e));

    this.source.addEventListener("open", e => this.onOpen(e), false);

    this.source.addEventListener("error", e => this.onError(e), false);

    // Add here (only mozilla)
    main();
    // Add here

  }
  StartRetrieveLiveData();
```

Do I need to use ajax callback? I am fairly new to SSE, and I am trying to get all the component right? it is a priority to pass the accelerometer data (sensorValue) from Onmsg to function main() so the model can move in real-time on the browser accordingly without any error or warning. Much appreciated.

P.S, below is was I wanted to achieve

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We will need to have `sunMesh` initialized either out of the scope of your main method or in the global scope to later access it.

Know that `sunMesh` would have to be initialized in your main method before you can access its position, so you might create a race condition if you don't do so synchronously (i.e. loading a model).

```js
let sunMesh;

function main() {
  sunMesh = new THREE.Mesh(...)
}

function onMsg(event) {
  const sensorValue = event.data;
  sunMesh.position.x = sensorValue;
}

// or, in the global scope (I'd try to avoid this)

function main() {
  window.sunMesh = new THREE.Mesh(...)
}

function onMsg(event) {
  const sensorValue = event.data;
  window.sunMesh.position.x = sensorValue;
}
```

Edit: As your message events are asynchronous, you would have to render inside of your animation loop or inside of the onMsg function in order to render updates (you would do the same with camera, scene, and renderer references as above).

```js
let sunMesh;

function main() {

  const canvas = document.querySelector('#canvas');
  const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ canvas });
  var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

  const fov = 70;
  const aspect = 2;
  const near = 20;
  const far = 500;
  const color = 0xFFFFFF;
  const intensity = 1;
  const size = 10;
  const divisions = 10;
  const objects = [];
  const radius = 3;
  const widthSegments = 3;
  const heightSegments = 3;
  const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(fov, aspect, near, far);
  const sphereGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(radius, widthSegments, heightSegments);
  const sunMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: "green", wireframe: false });
  sunMesh = new THREE.Mesh(sphereGeometry, sunMaterial)
  const light = new THREE.PointLight(color, intensity);
  // const gridHelper = new THREE.GridHelper(200000, 10000);

  camera.position.z = 0;
  camera.position.x = 100;
  camera.up.set(0, 0, 1);
  camera.lookAt(0, 0, 0);   

  const scene = new THREE.Scene();
  {
    const color = 0x00afaf;
    const intensity = 10;
    const light = new THREE.PointLight(color, intensity);
    scene.add(light);
    // gridHelper.geometry.rotateY(Math.PI / 2);
    // scene.add(gridHelper);
    // scene.add(light);
  }
  function resizeRendererToDisplaySize() {
  const canvas = renderer.domElement;
  const width = canvas.clientWidth;
  const height = canvas.clientHeight;
  const needResize = canvas.width !== width || canvas.height !== height;
  if (needResize) {
    renderer.setSize(width, height, false);
  }
  return needResize;
}

function resizeToClient() {
  const needResize = resizeRendererToDisplaySize()
  if (needResize) {
    const canvas = renderer.domElement;
    camera.aspect = canvas.clientWidth / canvas.clientHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  }
}

  var cubeAxis = new THREE.AxesHelper(10);
  sunMesh.add(cubeAxis);

  sunMesh.scale.set(5, 5, 5)
  scene.add(sunMesh);
  scene.background = new THREE.Color(0.22, 0.23, 0.22);

  function render() {
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
  }
  resizeToClient();
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}


function onMsg(event) {
  // console.log(`[message] Data received from server: ${event.data}`);
  // console.log("event.data = " + JSON.parse(event.data));

  var received_msg = event.data;

  var obj = JSON.parse(JSON.parse(received_msg));
  if (obj !== null) {
    if (
      obj.hasOwnProperty("DataMapChangedObjectsAddressValue") &&
      obj["DataMapChangedObjectsAddressValue"][0]["DataMapAddress"] !==
      undefined
    ) {
      let sensorAddr =
        obj["DataMapChangedObjectsAddressValue"][0]["DataMapAddress"];
      let sensorValue =
        obj["DataMapChangedObjectsAddressValue"][0]["Value"];

      //Accelerometer X Axis
      //if(sensorAddr === this.despToAddrMap.get("Accelerometer X Axis Data")){
      if (sensorAddr === 3) {
        console.log((sensorValue / 16384) * 500);
      }

      sunMesh.position.x = sensorValue;
    }
  }
}

function onOpen(e) {
  console.log("SSE connected");
}

function onError(e) {
  // console.log(`[error] ${error.message}`);
  if (e.eventPhase == EventSource.CLOSED) this.source.close();
  if (e.target.readyState == EventSource.CLOSED) {
    console.log("SSE Disconnected");
  } else if (e.target.readyState == EventSource.CONNECTING) {
    console.log("SSE Connecting ...");
  }
}

function StartRetrieveLiveData() {
  if (!!window.EventSource) {
    this.source = new EventSource("/sse");
  } else {
    console.log("Your browser doesn't support SSE");
  }

  this.source.addEventListener("message", e => this.onMsg(e));

  this.source.addEventListener("open", e => this.onOpen(e), false);

  this.source.addEventListener("error", e => this.onError(e), false);

  // Add here (only mozilla)
  main();
  // Add here

}
StartRetrieveLiveData();
```

Comment: but the sunMesh.position.x should run inside the function render() inside function main(), so I need to provide the sensorValue from onMsg back to function render(), it didn't as you suggested, what will be the solution to this?

Comment: You will have to move `renderer.render(scene, camera)` inside of your `render` function and have the `onMsg` function update the mesh's position (you would remove the old reference in the render function). You could also render from the `onMsg` function.

Comment: Could you please provide an example of this? I don't think I am doing it correctly

Comment: Sure. I'll put a snippet in the answer.

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a try shortly, I will mark it as answer when it works